# Hash Codes for Floats in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, hashcode

I have a class with two float variables and **hashCode** method (without equals in current code snippet):

```
public class TestPoint2D {
    private float x;
    private float z;

    public TestPoint2D(float x, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (x != +0.0f ? Float.floatToIntBits(x) : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (z != +0.0f ? Float.floatToIntBits(z) : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The following test

```
@Test
public void tempTest() {
    TestPoint2D p1 = new TestPoint2D(3, -1);
    TestPoint2D p2 = new TestPoint2D(-3, 1);

    System.out.println(p1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(p2.hashCode());
}
```

returns same values:

> -2025848832

In this case I can't use my TestPoint2D within HashSet / HashMap

Can anyone suggest how to implement **hashCode** in this case or workarounds related to this?

P.S.
Added one more test:

```
@Test
public void hashCodeTest() {
    for (float a = 5; a < 100000; a += 1.5f) {
        float b = a + 1000 / a; // negative value depends on a
        TestPoint3D p1 = new TestPoint3D(a, -b);
        TestPoint3D p2 = new TestPoint3D(-a, b);
        Assert.assertEquals(p1.hashCode(), p2.hashCode());
    }
}
```

And it is passed that proves that

`TestPoint2D(a, -b).hashCode() == TestPoint2D(-a, b).hashCode()`

Comment: Why don't you use `Float.hashCode()`?

Comment: I think you are looking for > (greater than) or < (less than), instead of != +0.0f. Try checking +ve or -ve using > or <, not by using !=

Comment: Why bother testing `x != 0.0f`? The answer of `Float.floatToIntBits(0.0f)` is already `0x00000000`.

Comment: So, **why** do you think you can't use `HashSet` / `HashMap`? I mean, other than the fact that you didn't implement `equals()`, but I assume that you did and just removed it from question for brevity. Hash values are not required to be distinct (aka different) for unequal objects, though it is much better if they are. It would actually be impossible to have such a requirement.

Comment: Further to @Andreas's comment, consider class `Long`. It has over four billion times as many distinct values as there are possible hashcodes. Obviously, a correctly written hash-based class must handle distinct objects with the same hash codes. Having two equal objects with different hash codes is a problem.

Comment: a small comments: 
1) a hashCode method was generated by Intellij IDEA;  
2) I wanted to use the mentioned object as key of hashSet/ hashMap

Comment: @JavaHopper, I believe that I should use TreeMap or something like that which uses .compare method ... but how should I implement it to make comparation efficient?

Comment: Do you **want** them to have the same hash code?!? That is a very different question! Or did you mean to use `assertNotEquals`? A quantitative test would be more reasonable, i.e. at most 1 hash collission in the 100x100 grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These auto-generated hashcode functions are not very good.

The problem is that small integers cause very "sparse" and similar bitcodes.

To understand the problem, look at the actual computation.

```
System.out.format("%x\n", Float.floatToIntBits(1));
System.out.format("%x\n", Float.floatToIntBits(-1));
System.out.format("%x\n", Float.floatToIntBits(3));
System.out.format("%x\n", Float.floatToIntBits(-3));
```

gives:

```
3f800000
bf800000
40400000
c0400000
```

As you can see, the `-` is the most significant bit in IEEE floats. Multiplication with 31 changes them not substantially:

```
b0800000
30800000
c7c00000
47c00000
```

The problem are all the 0s at the end. They get preserved by integer multiplication with any prime (because they are base-2 0s, not base-10!).

So IMHO, the best strategy is to employ bit shifts, e.g.:

```
final int h1 = Float.floatToIntBits(x);
final int h2 = Float.floatToIntBits(z);
return h1 ^ ((h2 >>> 16) | (h2 << 16));
```

But you may want to look at [Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed) and *test* for your particular case of integers-as-float.

Comment: I did tried '982451653' value instead of '31' but no luck ... don't think I should use larger numbers because they may not fit in Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Did you try my new variant, and see the explanation?

Comment: your updated answer looks acceptable for me! thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`Objects.hash()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-):

```
public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(x, z);
}
```

From the Javadoc:

> `public static int hash(Object... values)`
>
> Generates a hash code for a sequence of input values. The hash code is generated as if all the input values were placed into an array, and that array were hashed by calling Arrays.hashCode(Object[]).
>   This method is useful for implementing Object.hashCode() on objects containing multiple fields. For example, if an object that has three fields, x, y, and z, one could write:

Comment: or infact Float.hasCode(), as suggested by shmosel

Comment: That is definitely a better way to do it, but doesn't actually address the *perceived* issue in the question, i.e. the flawed assumption that two different objects that return the same hash code means that `HashSet` / `HashMap` cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you for Objects.hash method (I didn't know about it), but unfortunately Objects.hash(3.0f, -1.0f) === Objects.hash(-3.0f, 1.0f) :(

Comment: If you look at the **source of `Objects.hash()`** that is not at all surprising.

Answer (score 1):

according to the java specification, 2 objects can have the same hashCode and this doesnt mean they are equal...

the probability is small but [exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)...

on the other hand is always a good practice to override both equals and hashcode...

Comment: Yes, I know it ... but in my case    TestPoint2D(a, -b) === TestPoint2D(-a, b)  , where a and b - float point values .... I belive that this statement is applicable for most a/b pair .... on big amount of simmetric points we would get a huge collision :(

Comment: @Anony-Mousse , This test passed:
  for (float a = 5; a < 100000; a += 1.5f) {
   float b = a + 1000 / a; /* negative value depends on a */
   TestPoint3D p1 = new TestPoint3D(a, -b);
   TestPoint3D p2 = new TestPoint3D(-a, b);
   Assert.assertEquals(p1.hashCode(), p2.hashCode());
  }

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem, you expect a lot of symmetrical pairs of points among your keys, so you need a hashCode method that does not tend to give them the same code.

I did some tests, and deliberately giving extra significance to the sign of `x` tends to map symmetrical points away from each other. See this test program:

```
public class Test {
  private float x;
  private float y;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int collisions = 0;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < 100; ix++) {
      for (int iz = 0; iz < 100; iz++) {
        Test t1 = new Test(ix, -iz);
        Test t2 = new Test(-ix, iz);
        if (t1.hashCode() == t2.hashCode()) {
          collisions++;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(collisions);

  }

  public Test(float x, float y) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = (x >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
    result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(x);
    result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(y);
    return result;
  }
  // Equals omitted for compactness
}
```

Without the `result = (x >= 0) ? 1 : -1;` line it is the `hashCode()` generated by Eclipse, and counts 9802 symmetrical point collisions. With that line, it counts one symmetrical point collision.

Comment: I belive this will exhibit the same problem just somewhere similar. Say (x,y) and (y,x) without the minus.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse No, I just tested the (x,z) and (z,x) pattern and the only collisions were the inevitable ones for (x, x) and (x,x). Of course, there will be some patterns of inputs that have collisions because there are about 4 billion times as many ordered pairs of floats as there are ints.