# How to apply memoization in a GCD function in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have to calculate gcd of many pair of numbers, so for optimization I intend to apply memoization
to my function.

Pair class:

```
class Pair{
     private long a;
     private long b;
    
    Pair(long a,long b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

My hashmap (which is a static variable)

```
public static Map<Pair, Long> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
```

My gcd function:

```
public static long gcd(long a,long b) {
        
        if(hashmap.containsKey(new Pair(a,b))) {
            return hashmap.get(new Pair(a,b));
        }
        
        if(hashmap.containsKey(new Pair(b,a))) {
            return hashmap.get(new Pair(b,a));
        }
        
        if(a == 0) {
            return b;
        }
        
        long GCD = gcd(b%a,a);
        
        if(hashmap.containsKey(new Pair(a,b)) || hashmap.containsKey(new Pair(b,a))) {
            return GCD;
        }
        
        hashmap.put(new Pair(a,b),GCD);
        return GCD;
        
    }
```

However, when I print keys and values of my hashmap, it contains duplicates. This means that my function is not able to apply memoization, instead it is putting pair in the hashmap.

Comment: Types that are dedicated to being used as a key in a `HashMap` should (better read: must) overwrite the methods `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see some corrections to be made in your code.

- You don't have a `hashCode` defined for your `Pair` class. You could use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742634/1410303) to implement a hashCode for pair of longs.
- You don't have an `equals` method. You can just write `this.a == other.a && this.b == other.b` as the condition of equality. And `other` is an instance of `Pair`.
- This statement :

  `if(hashmap.containsKey(new Pair(a,b)) || hashmap.containsKey(new Pair(b,a))) { return GCD; }`

  is not needed. You already check it before invoking the recursive gcd
- Actually it shouldn't matter if the key is Pair(a,b) or Pair(b,a) the equals and hashCode should return the same and therefore you don't need to check

`if(hashmap.containsKey(new Pair(b,a))) {     return hashmap.get(new Pair(b,a)); }`